# Authentication.Federated settings not appearing

Tags: orchardcms

I'm trying to use the [Authentication.Federated](http://gallery.orchardproject.net/List/Modules/Orchard.Module.Authentication.Federated) module to enable ADFS support for Orchard.  I [installed](http://docs.orchardproject.net/Documentation/Installing-and-upgrading-modules) the module by downloading it locally and adding it, and I enabled the module.  Now, according to [the instructions](http://blog.maartenballiauw.be/post/2011/02/14/Authenticate-Orchard-users-with-AppFabric-Access-Control-Service.aspx), I should see the Federated authentication settings under the general "Settings" menu in the Orchard dashboard, but they are not there.  What's missing?

I'm running locally, if that's relevant, and I had Orchard setup its own local database when I started it the first time

**EDIT**:  Tried installing from Gallery; same thing.

**EDIT2**:  Looks like the logs show this:

> Orchard.Environment.Extensions.ExtensionManager - No suitable loader found for extension "Authentication.Federated"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the dynamic loader doesn't like Authentication.Federated, but the settings show up if you include the project in the solution.